# Get image preview to another div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a little problem with my image preview, because I would like get photo from #ImagePreview to #photo2 on click confirm button.

https://jsfiddle.net/0xd4odyf/3/

HTML

```
<img id="ImagePreview">
<input type="file" class="InputFile" onchange="document.getElementById('ImagePreview').src =window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])">
<div id="photo2"></div>
<button id="confirm">confirm</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you've already solved this problem, but perhaps someone will need it. Above problem is soloved using jquery, and I show solution using pure javascript.

```
let confirmButton = document.getElementById('confirm');
let photo2 = document.getElementById('photo2'); 
confirmButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  let srcAttr = document.getElementById('ImagePreview').getAttribute('src');
  let newImg = document.createElement('img');
  newImg.setAttribute('src', srcAttr);
  photo2.appendChild(newImg)
})
```

And the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1Lzpy42b/

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `src` attribute of the image (#ImagePreview) you selected and then set it as `background-image` attribute of the div(#photo2).

```
$("#confirm").click(function()
{
   var img = $('#ImagePreview').attr('src');
   $("#photo2").css('background-image','url(' + img + ')');
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/0xd4odyf/5/